# Как в AngularJS обработать ошибку 404 при аякс запросе?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS. При помощи `$http.get` обращаюсь к серверу, чтобы получить определенный объект. Этот объект либо есть, либо отсутствует. Если он есть, получаю его и произвожу какие-то действия. Но, если его нет, получаю ошибку в консоли...

> 404 (Not Found)

Как мне перехватить эту ошибку, чтобы не показывать ее пользователю в консоли?

Comment: никак - в консоли всегда выведется `404 (Not Found)` если такой ответ пришел от сервера

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Тогда вопрос в том, является ли хорошей практикой на сервере организовывать архитектуру таким образом, чтобы при отсутствии данных, возвращалась ошибка, а не, к примеру, пустой объект? И, возможно, проблему как-то решают интерцепторы? Стоит ли копать в эту сторону?

Comment: @Андрей, сервер должен возвращать ошибку. если подразумевается. что если нет данных - должна быть ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

```
$http({ 
    method: 'GET', 
    url: '/someUrl' 
}).then(
    function successCallback(response) {}, 
    function errorCallback(response) { 
         // обрабатываем ошибку
 });
```

response имеет следующие ключи:

**data** – {string|Object} – получаемое тело ответа от сервера.

**status** – {number} – HTTP код статуса

**headers** – {function([headerName])} – геттер на получения заголовков.

**config** – {Object} – конфиг запроса передаваемого на сервер

**statusText** – {string} – HTTP текст статуса с сервака

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*global angular*/
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular
  .module('App')
  .factory('httpErrorResponceInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$log',
              httpErrorResponceInterceptor]);

 httpErrorResponceInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$log'];

 /**
  * Интерцептор для перехвата ответов сервера, которые содержат ошибку.
  * Реализует обработку ошибочных ответов сервера (http кодов).
  * Реагирует только на коды 400, 401, 403, 404, и 500
  *
  * @name httpErrorResponceInterceptor
  */
 function httpErrorResponceInterceptor($q, $injector, $rootScope, $log) {
  var self = {};

  self.responseError = function (response) {
   var $http = $injector.get('$http');
   var $state = $injector.get('$state');
   var userFactory = $injector.get('userFactory');
   
   var jsonRegexp = /^application\/json;\s*charset=[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+/i;
   var m;
   /**
    * Проверяем что нам прислал сервер и если это JSON,
    * то ищем там текст сообщения и показываем его.
    */
   if((m = jsonRegexp.exec(response.headers()['content-type'])) !== null){
    var response_data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    if (response_data.messages &&
     angular.isArray(response_data.messages) &&
     response_data.messages.length > 0) {
     
     $log.debug("httpErrorResponceInterceptor:", response);
     $rootScope.ERROR_MESSAGES = response_data.messages;
    }
   }

   /**
    * Если пользователю для выполнения запроса необходима авторизация,
    * то сервер ответит кодом 401
    */
   if (response.status == 401){
    /**
     * Делаем разлогин пользователя, тем самым очищая содержимое сессии.
     * Это предусмотрено на тот случай, если вдруг сессия сохранится в localStorage,
     * а cookies удалены.
     */
    if(response_data.code && response_data.code !== 4001){
     userFactory.LogOut();
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
   }
   else if (response.status == 400){
    return $q.reject(response);
   }
   else if (response.status == 403) {
    return $q.reject(response);
   }
   else if (response.status == 404) {
    //$state.go("404");
    return $q.reject(response);
   }
   else if (response.status == 500) {
    return $q.reject(response);
   }
   
   return $http(response.config);
  };

  return self;
 }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

И потом в блоке config вашего приложения делаем так:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorResponceInterceptor');
```

Ну конечно исправьте под себя код )) Я из своего проекта скопипастил.